# event to detect ipad default keyboard hide key is pressed

Tags: ipad, uikeyboard, ios5.1

Is there any event or method to detect that I pressed the ipad's default hide keyboard button?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these notifications:

`UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` - Posted immediately prior to the dismissal of the keyboard.

`UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` - Posted immediately after the dismissal of the keyboard.

Source: [Managing the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

Comment: Yes @Adam you are correct. I guess the only way to do it is using Notifications. Thanks.